# Update all components whe use onClick event in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have conditional rendering. When i use onClick event all my components update.
My functions.

```
const reaction = (author) => {
    if (author == user.id){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}

const handleReactions = (reaction, id) =>{
    if (reaction === 'like'){
        httpClient.put(`/likes/${id}/`)
            .then((response) => {
                alert(response.data);
            })
    }
}
```

My return

```
return (
    {reaction(post.user)
     ?<form>
      <button type="submit" name="like" value={post.id} onClick={handleReactions('like', post.id)}>
    : //another conditional
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```js
    return (
    {reaction(post.user)
     ?<form>
      <button type="submit" name="like" value={post.id} onClick={() => handleReactions('like', post.id)}>
    : //another conditional
    })
```

Explanation: you are calling handleReactions directly instead of giving the function to execute when the button is clicked. Solution define lambda function which is calling your function inside

PS : your function :

```js
const reaction = (author) => {
    if (author == user.id){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

Can be simplified:

```js
const reaction = (author) => author != user.id
```